# how to trigger click event on <ion -radio> using angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having this radio buttons i have to trigger click event to get checked radio button.I know I can  make it checked using ng-model value that should be equal to value attribute. but i have to check using click event.

```
<ion-radio value="first" id="first"> First </ion-radio>
<ion-radio value="second" id="second"> Second </ion-radio>
```

Comment: add ng-click on element

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to use "ng-change" ?

Answer (score 0):

ng-click should work for you. Because I have the same requirement you've mentioned and ng-click is working perfectly for me.

Hope it will work for you as well!